# Conditional JQuery css only working once

Tags: jquery, html, css

We have a simple HTML page with a few span tags, and need to change the css style of the text depending on what they contain. This works fine for the FIRST occurence on the page, but not for the second (presumably all later occurences).

```
$(function(){
  $("span#someId:contains('Text to change red')").css('color','red');
});
```

The spans look like this:

```
<td><span id="someId">Text to change red</span></td>
```

If this same span (with the same id..) is repeated on the page, only the first occurence displays red - it should turn them all red. What's going on?

Comment: Need to wrap that in a document.ready and make sure to reference the external js on every page that you'll be using it.

Comment: The `id` must be unique across all elements on a page.

Comment: To expand, I assume it is for performance reasons. Since `id`s should be unique, once it finds one, there's no reason to keep looking for more.

Comment: Granted, I figured the IDs should probably be unique. But I didn't write this junky old code and do not want to change anything more than absolutely necessary. I consider it a semi-debatable bug in (JQuery?), since it SHOULD work for all IDs regardless of re-use. Performance is a 'plausible' reason so I guess that answers the curiosity portion of the question..

Comment: Id has to be unique according to the 1999 HTML 4.0 specification.  Long time ago to have written incompatible code - so the bug is in the original code here, not some library adhering to the specifications.  SO, the change is needed to make it work like this, whether desired or not is up to you.

Comment: Actually, this thing is somewhere around that old (also consider the dev tools & platform here are usually a few years out of date), but probably not the lib. Not defending crappy code/script. Legacy html apps are garbage and this is all unproductive tech, so my patience wears thin with problems like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use classes not an ID (as IDs should be unique - 1 per page):

```
<td><span class="myspan">Text to change red</span></td>
```

And then:

```
$("span.myspan:contains('Text to change red')").css('color','red');
```

Or, if the only important part is the text in the span you can simplify it to something like:

```
$("td span:contains('Text to change red')").css('color','red'); //If td is even needed!
```